# How to get the IP address of a client using aiohttp

Tags: python, django, websocket, aiohttp

I am currently working on a django project where I use aiohttp to communicate between the backend and frontend. I wanted to get the IP address of a client when a request is made from the frontend. Looked in different docs but none seems to point to exactly how to get the IP address using aiohttp. Someone Help!

```
from aiohttp import web


async def handler(request):

    ws = web.WebSocketResponse()
    await ws.prepare(request)

    try:
        async for msg in ws:
            # handle incoming messages
            # use ws.send_str() to send data back
            ...

    finally:
        task.cancel()
```

Comment: Can you try `request.remote`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the [aiohttp docs](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_reference.html#aiohttp.web.BaseRequest.remote) you can get the originating IP address of a client initiated HTTP request from requests `remote` parameter (`request.remote`).